# Using controllers with Slim Framework v4?

Tags: php, slim

Based on [the official documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#allow-slim-to-instantiate-the-controller) I am trying to use a controller without registering in the container.

However I am getting this error:
**App\Controller\HomeController::__construct(): Argument #1 ($container) must be of type Psr\Container\ContainerInterface, null given**

My app/HomeController.php file:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class HomeController
{
   private $container;

   // constructor receives container instance
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
   {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function home(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, array $args): ResponseInterface
   {
        // your code to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');

        return $response;
   }

   public function contact(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, array $args): ResponseInterface
   {
        // your code to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');

        return $response;
   }
}
```

public/index.php file:

```
use App\Controller\HomeController;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', HomeController::class . ':home');

$app->run();
```

And here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "4.*",
        "slim/psr7": "^1.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Slim app instance needs a DI container instance that can then be passed into the controller.

Comment: @odan do you have any code examples or documentation about it?

Comment: Yes, see here: [Slim Dependency Container](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/di.html) and my blog post [Slim 4 - PHP-DI](https://odan.github.io/2020/05/24/slim4-php-di.html), [Tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html)